# File conversion and substitution with python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, converters

I am trying to create a python3 program that would convert a text file from one format to a custom format. I am unsure if I need to use regex to specify the sections of text or if there is an easier way.

I have already wrote the code to read the files, create a new folder, export the new file format but I need guidance on the substitution process.

## Input file format

Item1_Number=501

Item2_Number=502

## Template File format

Memory Key 1       :000

Memory Key 2       :000

## Where I need help

I'd like to be able to create a list of substitution values for ex. Item1_Number = Memory Key 1

I need to create a loop in order to grab the number from the first value and substitute that number into the template's equivalent value.

I need grab the "501" in Item_Number and overwrite the value in Memory Key 1 with the "501"

I have spent plenty of time searching misc forums for answers but I haven't found anything that has helped me. If this exact type of question has been answered then I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use regex in python to capture group and replace. Assuming that your input has those constant always and only numeric values are variable size then you should be able to do following:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "Item1_Number=501"
>>> re.sub(r"Item(\d+)_Number=(\d+)", r"Memory Key \1 :\2", a)
'Memory Key 1 :501'
```

You should preferably compile regex first and use it instead of creating for each line. Also, back reference for a matched group can be done more effectively.

Comment: I appreciate the response and I understand your answer. I see how I can now do that for that example but I was wondering if there was a way to read everything before the '=' in the input file and store it as a variable and do the same with the template file. I will be parsing over 100 lines and they only have one thing in common, the input file will have the name and the value seperated with a '=' and the template file will have the name and value seperated with a ':'

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Above operation can be done per line and you can be reading a line at a time and writing output to the template file. If you want template to be also configurable you can read that line and use simple string parsing or regex groups to read matched groups. That way you can process each line with templated output based on your template file.